# PatternSyntaxException unclosed group

Tags: java, regex

I have this RegEx String..

`String regex = ^(/|\\){2}(projects|depot|perforce_[0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\\1)q(uality|a)]+)(\\1)$`

String test cases that should match with this regex:

1. //depot/quality/
2. \\projects\qa\
3. //perforce_0tests001/quality/

Explanation for this regex:

1. match beginning
2. group1: / *or* \ (only two times)
3. group2: depot *or* projects *or* perforce_xn where xn is any digit or letter
4. group3: references group1 only once
5. q
6. group4: uality *or* a
7. group5: references group1 only once
8. match end

This regex is failing with the following exception with string //depot/quality/

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 64
^(/|\){2}(projects|depot|perforce_[0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\1)q(uality|a)(\1)$
                                                                ^
```

My other problem is that I want to also allow in group1 the vertical bar character: |

So that the following string also matches: ||depot|quality|

How can I do that? I don't know how to escape it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String regex = "^(\\/|\\\\|\\|){2}(projects|depot|perforce_[0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\\1)q(uality|a)(\\1)$";
```

This Java regex String should work fine for you. As you can see `\\|` will be parsed in Java to `\|` which is a regex escape for the vertical bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong regexp. You should use : 
`(\/\/|\\){1}(projects|depot|(perforce_[0-9a-z]+))(\\|\/)(quality|qa)(\\|\/)`

This is for java:

```
String pattern = "(\\/\\/|\\\\){1}(projects|depot|(perforce_[0-9a-z]+))(\\\\|\\/)(quality|qa)(\\\\|\\/)";
```

It works fine.

If you wanna use `||depot|quality|`(in regexp it is `\|`), that you should use the following:

```
(\/\/|\\|\||\|\|){1}(projects|depot|(perforce_[0-9a-z]+))(\\|\/|\|)(quality|qa)(\\|\/|\|)
```

If you explain more clearer what you want, then I can help you more precisely. If you wanna match only one string like //depot/quality/, that it works fine,  but if you wanna parse huge document, then regexp will be a little bit different.

Comment: first part is correct. thanks; second part: edit it to be `\\|` so that I accept your answer

Comment: I trying understand your regexp, You wanna use in the end of your examples '1' or something else? I mean something like that : //depot/quality/1 ?

Comment: @rz3r0, btw, you should format my second regexp for java version. It's "`(\\/\\/|\\\\|\\||\\|\\|){1}(projects|depot|(perforce_[0-9a-z]+))(\\\\|\\/|\\|)(quality|qa)(\\\\|\\/|\\|)"`

Comment: no the ` \1 ` is meant to backreference the group number1 so that if group1 has ` \ ` then ` \1 ` should also have ` \ `